# Failing to build a liferay project with eclipse (Ant ivy)

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, liferay-6, ivy

I'm getting  this error

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\---\---\---\build-common-ivy.xml:7: Problem: failed to create task or type if
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

It seems to fail at the line where i define the property name="ivy.home":

```
<project name="build-common-ivy" xmlns:antelope="antlib:ise.antelope.tasks" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
    <property name="ivy.home" value="${sdk.dir}/.ivy" />

<if>
        <not>
            <available file="${ivy.home}/ivy-${ivy.version}.jar" />
        </not>
        <then>
          ...
```

I think it's the ${sdk.dir} that isn't defined, but where I can define it?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use ant-contrib's `<if>` task, but you haven't loaded ant-contrib's tasks in your script. For the record, I recommend avoiding the use of ant-contrib at all costs. It leads to systemic problems in scripts, and the vast majority of the time vanilla Ant will do what you're need more quickly, safely, and elegantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @CAustin your issue is that the "if" task is not a standard ANT feature. It's part of the 3rd party extension to ANT, called [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/), and I would agree it's best avoided.

If you want to automate the conditional installation of ivy, try something like the following:

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <available classname="org.apache.ivy.Main" property="ivy.installed"/> 

    <target name="install-ivy" unless="ivy.installed">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.4.0/ivy-2.4.0.jar"/>
        <fail message="Ivy has been installed. Run the build again"/>
    </target>

    <target name="resolve" depends="install-ivy">
        <ivy:resolve/>

        ..
        ..
```

Hope this helps